# Subprocess Tornado capture exit status

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, tornado

Scenario: First, I need to update status in db to 'pending' and at the same time, return the status to user. Then subprocess will be running in the background and it will take 30 seconds as I have put `time.sleep(30)` in dummy.py. After that, I have to update status in db to 'completed'. I am trying to make non-blocking functions using tornado.
My Question: I have captured if Subprocess is finished by using yield. If yield result is 0, I assume that Subprocess has completed. I know something is not right with my logic. How do I capture if Subprocess(Tornado) has finished in correct way? 
My current code is:

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
@coroutine
def get(self, id):
    print ("TORNADO ALERT")
    self.write("Pending")
    #If ID in DB, UPDATE DB
    #Update Status to Pending 
    self.flush()
    res =yield self._work()

    self.write(res)

@coroutine
def _work(self):
    p = Subprocess(['python', 'dummy.py'])
    f = Future()
    p.set_exit_callback(f.set_result)
    h = yield f
    print (">>> ",h)
    if h == 0:
        print("DB Updated")
        #Update Status to Completed
    raise Return(" Completed ")
```

My imports are as follows:

```
from tornado.concurrent import Future
from tornado.process import Subprocess
```

Comment: Can you please add the imports in the code snippet (in particular for ``Future``)?

Comment: I have added import for furture

Comment: What is your OS? [set_exit_callback won't work on Windows](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/process.html#tornado.process.Subprocess)

Comment: I am working on Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Use `Subprocess.wait_for_exit()` (which returns a Future) instead of `Subprocess.set_exit_callback()`. This can then be used in a coroutine with

```
async def f():
    p = Subprocess(cmd)
    await p.wait_for_exit()
```

Comment: I want to update DB after subprocess has finished. 

`def _work(self):
        p = Subprocess([cmd])
        f = Future()
        p.wait_for_exit(f.set_result)
        #if p has finished:
           #Update DB
        raise Return ("Hello World")`

I'm having difficulty there. Code flow should be, return "Hello World" to user while Subprocess is doing its job. After it is finished, update DB.

Comment: Please update your question (not just a comment) with more details about what you're doing and how it's failing. Note that you must either use coroutines or callbacks here; plain functions won't work.

Comment: The code looks fine to me. I'd still recommend using wait_for_exit instead of set_exit_callback(future.set_result), but they should be equivalent. You say "I know something is not right with my logic"; how do you know this? What exactly is happening and what did you expect instead?

Comment: I said it because I'm new to Tornado, especially, I do not really know how to use "Future". However, the code is working as it was intended. It was just my gut feeling. Thanks for helping out @Ben. It is nice for me to know someone's there to help along with new framework and programming language.